# Streaming audio from microphone via express wont play in VLC media player (or anything else)

Tags: node.js, express, streaming, audio-streaming, ogg

I'm trying to stream my microphone audio via nodejs express to a local url.

When accessing the url it will connect and the debug code will trigger, but it will not begin to play the audio and will continue loading infinitely.

```
var mic = require("mic");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var micInstance = mic({
    rate: "16000",
    channels: "1",
    //debug: true,
    fileType: "ogg"
});
let micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();

micInputStream.on("error", function(err) {
    cosole.log("Error: " + err);
});

micInputStream.on("startComplete", function() {
    console.log("Started recording");
});
micInstance.start();

app.get("/stream.oga", function (req, res) {
    res.set("content-type", "audio/ogg");
    res.set("transfer-encoding", "chunked");

    micInputStream.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log("Writing chunk: " + data.length);
        res.write(data);
    });
    console.log("##DEBUG Started piping");

    //micInputStream.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Where do you convert from PCM to oog?

Comment: I was under the impression that since the mic library fileType is set to ogg it would output ogg.